# Layered Bar charts in javascript

Tags: javascript, charts

Hi anyone ever tried creating Layered Bar chart with any Open source javascript library ? While googling out I found that people talk about stacked bar chart, but not layered chart anywhere. A Layered bar chart looks like in the image and it is supported by Java freecharts.

[image]

Any suggestion on libraries that gives the chart directly would be great. Otherwise I should go with d3.js I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with amCharts: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/layered-column-chart/

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "theme": "none",
    "type": "serial",
    "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "USA",
        "year2004": 3.5,
        "year2005": 4.2
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "year2004": 1.7,
        "year2005": 3.1
    }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "year2004": 2.8,
        "year2005": 2.9
    }, {
        "country": "Japan",
        "year2004": 2.6,
        "year2005": 2.3
    }, {
        "country": "France",
        "year2004": 1.4,
        "year2005": 2.1
    }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "year2004": 2.6,
        "year2005": 4.9
    }],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "unit": "%",
        "position": "left",
        "title": "GDP growth rate",
    }],
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "GDP grow in [[category]] (2004): [[value]]",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "title": "2004",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "year2004"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "GDP grow in [[category]] (2005): [[value]]",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
        "title": "2005",
        "type": "column",
        "clustered":false,
        "columnWidth":0.5,
        "valueField": "year2005"
    }],
    "plotAreaFillAlphas": 0.1,
    "categoryField": "country",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start"
    }
});
```

The trick is you must set "clustered" property of graph to false and columnWidth to some smaller value, like 0.5 or so.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using d3.js ?

Answer (score 0):

RGraph has a demo of that in the RGraph download called:

```
demos/bar-in-bar.html
```

You can download RGraph from the website:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable

Comment: Is there a way to do it using d3.js ?